# Bash: Formating numbers in a n digit string

Tags: bash, string-formatting

I am a bash newbie. I would like to echo the numbers 1 to `x` in a `n` digits format. For example, let's consider `n=3`: 5 should become 005, 13 should become 013, 110 should remain 110.

One way to achieve this is with this kind of structure:

```
for i in $(seq 1 120)
do
   if [ "$i" -lt "10" ]
   then
      echo "00$i"
   elif [ "$i" -gt "99" ]
   then
      echo "$i"
   else
      echo "0$i"
   fi
done
```

but it is quite ugly and is really not flexible to changing values of `n` (number of digits). I'd rather have a function that just do the formatting in `n` digits? Is there an already built in function for that? If not can you help me to create such function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
for i in {1..120} ; do
    printf '%03d\n' $i
done
```

- `%` starts the format string
- `d` means *integer*
- `3` means *length = 3*
- `0` means *zero padded*
- `\n` is a newline

Comment: The format specifier `%03d` means "pad with the character `0` to a length of 3, the input is a signed decimal number".

Comment: Thank you that perfectly answers my question +1. If I may ask a follow-up question: Is there a way to work out with this string to read a file for example rather than just printing it on the screen?

Comment: @Remi.b: To read input, use `read`. To write to a file, use redirection.

Comment: This code could be changed to `printf '%03d\n' {1..120}` (no need for a loop), or you could even use `printf '%s\n' {001..120}`.

Comment: Note that `{001..120}` is only supported in version 4 or later, which could be an issue if you are using Mac OS X (which only ships `bash` 3.2).

Comment: @TomFenech: The latter doesn't work in older bashes where you need `{0{0{1..9},{1..9}{0..9}},1{{0,1}{0..9},20}}`

Comment: @choroba thank you. The answer I found to my follow up question was var="$(printf `%03d\n 12`)". Sorry, I suppose the follow up question was a bit unclear. But anyway, I got it now!